# How to add the same field as "assignee" in jira task?

Tags: jira

I need to add custom field "developer" in jira.
To see who was working on this ticket when (for example) we return back ticket from QA to "need fixes". The same as "assignee", but additional.
I saw that I can add custom field - but standard "user picker" field doesn't work for me - I have to specify the exact nickname, cause this field doesn't have search.
Are there any options for me to add this kind of field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom field of type `User Picker (Single User)`.

Name it `Developer`.

Place this field on the masks you need it on.

Comment: How to add search to this field? When I add it to my tickets it can be filled only with precise nickname, it doesn't have search

Comment: The User Picker does come with the autocomplete... it should behave pretty much like the assignee. If you can search in the assignee field, you should also be be able to search in a custom user picker field.
Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yeah, it's strange, but mine doesn't have it... When I start typing in assignee field - it shows me options, but User Picker won't. May it be because of Jira version? I've got v7.1.7 right now

Comment: actually it even has "lock" icon near it when I'm creating a ticket

Comment: That explains it. This bug ist fixed in Jira 7.1.8:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-45836?_ga=2.85099161.1465747544.1593415459-1132282397.1590409375